# OO javascript - context/scope of self executing function in Constructor function

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question regarding context/scope when using a self executing anon function within a Constructor function.

Observe the following working code:

```
function Foo() {
    this.height = 10;
    this.width = 10;
    this.init = function() {
        this.create();
    };
    this.create = function() {
        alert('test');
    };
} 

var span1 = new Foo();
span1.init();
```

The alert is displayed as predicted. However, I dont want to call span1.init at the bottom. I would rather have the init function in the Constructor function be self executing. This would give me code like below:

```
function Foo() {
    this.height = 10;
    this.width = 10;
    this.init = (function() {
        this.create();
    })();
    this.create = function() {
        alert('test');
    };
} 

var span1 = new Foo();
```

However, after some Googling, seemingly using a self executing gives it global scope and thus this.create doesn't exist in the global sense.

I think I have to do something with call/apply but I am not sure what or where exactly.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Ad.

Comment: Why do you need a self-executing function? Just leave away all the function stuff and execute it in the constructor scope.

Answer (score 2):

Adi, there are two problems with what you've done in the example.
The first problem is that inside of the immediately-invoked function, `this === window`.

The second problem is that these are all function-expressions.
As such, they are all being defined in-line.

```
function makeIt () {
    this.a = function () { this.b(); };
    this.b = function () { console.log("B"); };
}
```

This is going to work because of late-static binding.
What that means is that inside of `a`, the browser has no idea what `this` refers to until the moment the function is called.  Then it finds the object that `this` refers to at that exact moment in time.

Otherwise, it would be just like assigning variables:

```
function makeIt () {
    this.a = this.b;
    this.b = "George";
}
```

There you're going to get an error.
Why?  Simply because by the time you're assigning `a`, `b` doesn't have a value yet.

```
function Foo () {
    this.init = (function (context) { context.change(); }(this));
    this.change = function () { doStuff(); };
}
```

So what's the problem with this statement?
Well, ***immediately-invoking functions are functions which invoke immediately***.
That means that even though we've solved the `this` problem, by passing the value of `this` as a parameter to the inner-scope...

...we're asking it to run something that doesn't exist yet.

```
function Foo () {
    this.change = function () { doStuff(); };
    this.init = (function (context) { context.change(); }(this));
}
```

That should work just fine.
...however...

...why would you bother to do it that way?
As in, why would you give it a `public` `init` property (which is `undefined`) when you want it to construct automatically?

Why is `init` `undefined`?  Because you're not returning anything -- you're running a function and setting `init` to the return value of the function, but it's not returning anything, so it sets `init` to `undefined`.  Why have `init` there at all, then?

Two solutions:

```
function Foo () {
    this.change = function () { doStuff(); };
    var init = function () { this.change(); };
    // other stuff......
    init();
}
```

or:

```
function Foo () {
    this.change = function () { doStuff(); };
    // other stuff....


    (function (context) {
       context.change();
       /* a bunch of other stuff that would be in init
          if there was no other stuff, why not just call this.change()? */
    }(this));
}
```

And honestly, if `init` is meant to be private, and run automatically, does `create` really need to be public?
Are you going to call `myObj.create();` after it's already been created?

Why not do something like:

```
function Foo () {
    this.public1 = "Bob";
    this.public2 = 32;
    this.publicMethod = function () {};

    var create = function () { /* initialize here */ };
    create();
}
```

Or again, if you're doing more than just `create`:

```
function Foo () {
    this.public1 = "Bob";
    this.public2 = 32;
    this.arrayOfThings = [];
    this.publicMethod = function () {};

    var create = function () {},
        overclock = function () {},
        polish = function () {};

    // Initialize Everything
    (function (context) {
        var thing;
        for (/* ... */) {
            thing = create();
            polish(thing);
            context.arrayOfThings.push(thing);
        }
        overclock(context.arrayOfThings); 
    }(this));
}
```

Now, you've got all of your functions and your properties and your variables in one scope, and you've got your initialization in another -- all of the setup logic is separate from the final object's logic...  ...and you can do things like branching your objects based on input parameters (like a polymorphic constructor, which would modify what it gave you, based on what it got, while maintaining the same interface -- or a self-contained factory pattern where all blueprints are 100% private and enclosed), without making the actual assignments look like a mess of ifs and fors.

You don't have to call the setup outside of the finished object (which means that nobody else ***can*** call the setup on the finished object, to recreate it/reset it).  And all it cost was one anonymous function you were going to use on `this.init` anyway.

Comment: +1, although your last example still lacks a correct `this` value

Comment: Hah.  Whoops.  Yes.  Aside from passing context into the last function, I figured that these would be suitable-enough to get the job done.  I'm going to fix that now -- thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass the context to the new closure:

```
this.init = (function(ctx) {
    ctx.create();
})(this);
```

Note that this is executed at the time that `init` is declared, so it won't work unless you assign `create` *before* you assign `init`. In your former example this is not a problem since `span1.init()` is called manually after both `create` and `init` have been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

That how it works (see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jw8jz/1/):

```
function Foo() {
  this.height = 10;
  this.width = 10;

  this.init();
}

Foo.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    this.create();
  },

  create: function() {
    alert('test');
  }
};

var span = new Foo();
```

Learn more about prototype property!

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP wishes not to call `spa​n.init();​`.

Comment: actually, I would recommend against setting `Foo.prototype` to an object literal, as this will overwrite any possible existing properties on `.prototype`. Better to define `.prototype.init` and `.prototype.create` individually

Comment: @SperanskyDanil when you do this, you crush the entire prototype chain above this point.  If there are any prototype properties which are connected to constructors before this level, then they'll all be erased.  Think about the difference between `bob = {name : "Bob"}; bob.age = 32;` and `bob = { name : "Bob" }; bob = { age : 32 };`  If you've stacked your prototype instances in one way or another, in order to attempt an inheritance pattern that isn't flat, then you've crushed the whole chain except the last stop.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but maybe what you want is:

```
function Foo() {
    this.height = 10;
    this.width = 10;
    this.init = function() {
        this.create();
    };
    this.create = function() {
        alert('test');
    };

    this.init();
}
```

Of course, similarly, you can remove the `init` function altogether, or make it private. For example:

```
function Foo() {
    this.height = 10;
    this.width = 10;
    this.create = function() {
        alert('test');
    };

    this.create();
}
```

In addition, note that `this.init = (function() {})();` sets `this.init` to `undefined`, because your function return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) will work ([`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) just has a different arguments parameter, which you don't use at all):

```
this.init = (function() {
    this.create();
    // return something?
}).call(this);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What do you expect it to do?